# Weird behaviour with python in jupyter notebook; is this a bug or should I just accept it as it is?

Tags: python, oop, jupyter-notebook, instance, class-variables

I was tinkering on a little project idea in jupyter notbook when I stumbled across some weird behaviour...
The following code is abstracted from the original.

```
class MyClass:
    Instances = []
    
    def __init__(self,name=None):
        self.id = len(MyClass.Instances)
        MyClass.Instances.append(self)
        
        if name is None:
            self.name = 'Class %s' % self.id
        else:
            self.name = name
    
    def show(self):
        print('Name: %s\nId: %s' % (self.name, self.id))

    def instance_at(i : int):
        if i >= len(MyClass.Instances):
            raise ValueError("Instance does not exist")
        return MyClass.Instances[i]
```

(I hope the code is self-explanatory)

I ran the cell and tested the code and it work fine:

```
In [24] :   m = MyClass()
            m.show()

Out [25] :  Name: Class 0
            Id: 0
```

The Twist:

I didn't like that the first instance, with no name given, would be called 'Class 0' so I thought to myself: 'Why not add an object which will act as a placeholder for the index 0' (Don't ask why I did this, 'twas a brainfart).

So I changed line 2 to be `Instances = [MyClass(name='id')`. This also worked but when I tried to receive the instance at index 0, it's id value was different to what I expected.

```
In [24] :   m = MyClass()
            m.show()
            MyClass.instance_at(0).show()

Out [25] :  Name: Class 0
            Id: 1
            Name: id
            Id: 1
```

This was the point where I decided to write a more generalized version of my code (the one shown here) in another notebook. I wrote it whole before running the cell, including `Instances = [MyClass(name='id')]`.

This time I got this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-60020e1975a4> in <module>
----> 1 class MyClass:
      2     Instances = [MyClass(name='id')]
      3     #Instances = []
      4 
      5     def instance_at(i : int):

<ipython-input-1-60020e1975a4> in MyClass()
      1 class MyClass:
----> 2     Instances = [MyClass(name='id')]
      3     #Instances = []
      4 
      5     def instance_at(i : int):

NameError: name 'MyClass' is not defined
```

So now I have a piece of code which runs in one notebook but not in another. At least when you simply copy and paste it. In jupyter notebook this is fixable by changing line 2 to `Instances = []`, running the cell and changing it back.

I am fairly certain that this is because the class and the class variable `Instances` already existed before I created the ambiguous line of code.

In hindsight, this does make sense and I suspect the unexpected id value comes from a constructor call being discovered in the list when the instance `m` is being created.

Am I wrong? Can anybody elaborate?

Please let me know if a post like this is inappropriate here.

Comment: "So I changed line 2 to be `Instances = [MyClass(name='id')`. This also worked" This is not reproducible. Doing this will **not** use the definition of `MyClass` that you are currently writing. It will use the *previous* `MyClass`, if it's still available in your session; if you restart and try to use a class like this (or start from scratch in a new source file), it will produce an error.

Comment: "This time I got this:... So now I have a piece of code which runs in one notebook but not in another." That's because it doesn't actually "work" anything like what you expect at all, but "in one notebook" you hadn't started fresh.

Comment: That said: trying to "auto-register" every instance you create of a class is *almost certainly a design mistake*. Just let the calling code make lists *of the instances that bit of code cares about*. Depending on the overall code structure, that may or may not be all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler example:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Creating an instance of the OLD class")

class Example: # redefining like this does **not** cause an error
    Instances = [Example()]
    def __init__(self):
        print("Creating an instance of the NEW class")
    
# the OLD message is printed immediately
# because `Instances = [Example()]` uses the previous definition
# because it **cannot** use the current one; it hasn't been created yet.

# You **do** get an error **without** the old definition, because then
# there isn't a definition at all.

x = Example() # the NEW message is printed
# the OLD class **still exists**, but cannot easily be accessed.
# As long as we can think of a way to get at an instance,
# we can use the `__class__` of the instance to create more;
# and we can rename that to make it easily usable:
Old_Example = Example.Instances[0].__class__
y = Old_Example()
```